# gzfactory spawning not working in Gazebo 1.2

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

**1)I am trying to spawn an sdf model using the gzfactory command line tool.

For this command I get the following error:**

*$gzfactory spawn -f .gazebo/models/table/model.sdf -m table -x 1 -y 1 -z 2 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0*

Error [SDF.cc:987] Unable to find value for key[origin]
Error [SDF.cc:741] Missing element description for [origin]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**2)If I try to spawn it from a world plugin via msgs::Factory messages on the "~/factory" topic.**

msgs::Factory msg;
msg.set_sdf_filename("~/.gazebo/models/table/model.sdf");
msgs::Set(msg.mutable_pose(), math::Pose(math::Vector3(0.3, 0.5, 0.945), math::Quaternion(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)))
factoryPub->Publish(msg);

**OR with:

_parent->InsertModelFile("models/table/model.sdf");

**
I get these errors:

Error [SystemPaths.cc:281] Unknown URI prefix[~/.gazebo/models/table/model.sdf]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:219] Unable to download model[~/.gazebo/models/table/model.sdf]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:391] Invalid model manifest file[/manifest.xml]
Error [World.cc:1201] Unable to read sdf file.

**How am I supposed to add a local model to gazebo ??**

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/433/gzfactory-spawning-not-working-in-gazebo-1.2/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is indeed broken. I've created a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/289/gzfactory-command-line-tool-broken) for this issue.

---

Originally posted by [natepak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57/natepak/) with karma: 111 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0